# OpenGL - how to fit a window on resize

Tags: c++, opengl, resize

I have a shape that is centered on the window screen. For now on window resize it remains the same (same width and height).
What is the best way to fit it to the window on resize, and also keep it's aspect ratio?

```
const int WIDTH = 490;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

/**
* render scene
*/
void renderScene(void)
{
    //clear all data on scene
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //set white bg color
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    glColor3ub(153, 153, 255);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(60, 310);
        glVertex2f(245, 50);
        glVertex2f(430, 310);
        glVertex2f(245, 530);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

/**
* reshape scene
*/
void reshapeScene(GLint width, GLint height)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, height, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

/**
* entry point
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //set window properties
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition((glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)-WIDTH)/2, (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT)-HEIGHT)/2);
    glutCreateWindow("Test Window");

    //paste opengl version in console
    printf((const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    //register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeScene);

    //start animation
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You could resize the front clipping plane to fit the dimensions of the new window size. That would not keep the aspect ratio, but it wouldn't scale the view.

Comment: I resize it to the dimensions of the window size using glViewport(0, 0, width, height); and gluOrtho2D(0, width, height, 0); I'm not sure I do it right..

Comment: That does not adjust for aspect ratio. If you wanted to keep a constant aspect ratio you would need to compute the (initial) ratio of width to height and multiply `width` by that instead of using `height` when you call `gluOrtho2D (...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top:

```
const int WIDTH = 490;
const int HEIGHT = 600;
const float ASPECT = float(WIDTH)/HEIGHT;   // desired aspect ratio
```

Then `reshapeScene`:

```
void reshapeScene(GLint width, GLint height)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    int w = height * ASPECT;           // w is width adjusted for aspect ratio
    int left = (width - w) / 2;
    glViewport(left, 0, w, height);       // fix up the viewport to maintain aspect ratio
    gluOrtho2D(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);   // only the window is changing, not the camera
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Because you are not constraining the window resize to a particular aspect ratio, you need to pick one of the two dimensions (height, here) to drive the viewport reshape and calculate an adjusted width based on that height and the desired aspect ratio. See adjusted `glViewport` call above.

Also, `gluOrtho2D` is your camera, essentially. Since you aren't moving the camera or the object so much, you don't need to change that (so it just uses the initial `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`).

Comment: I made a small change, calculating the left side of the viewport, which will keep your object centered in the window. It's not as simple as it could be, if your camera was centered looking at the origin, but it works.

Comment: It looks even better! 
I see that there is a kind of dependency between glViewport and gluOrtho2D. If I change one of them, it effects on another one. How are they dependant?

Comment: @no81no You'll need to read up on coordinate systems along the graphics pipeline. (See **The global picture** here: http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems)

Comment: To continue: Realize that some coordinate (1, 2, 3) can mean different things depending on context. Is that related to the object? To the camera? To the screen (which is only 2D and not 3D)? How do you transition from object to world to camera to screen?  A thorough understanding of these spaces will be important to getting graphics right.  Granted, 2D is much simpler than 3D, but even with 2D, knowing those coordinate systems will remove the guesswork in getting everything correct.